# How to Get the Absolutepath Without the Id or Query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, absolute-path

Let's say my url is "https://www.mywebsite.com/app/company/employees/5" or "https://www.mywebsite.com/company/employees?id=5&name=jack"

I'm looking for a way to get the "base" path, or whatever it's called. Like the "base" path would be "/app/company/employees" for both, without the "/5"  part or "?id=5&name=jack" part.

I was using `string.Join("/", request.ApplicationPath, request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"], request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"])` to get it (request is HttpRequestBase), but it doesn't work the way I want since it includes the Index action too. Like if the Url is "https://www.mywebsite.com/app/company" I want "/app/company/" not "/app/company/Index". I can always check if the action is Index or not but it feels like kind of a "code smell" to me.

Is it even a code smell? Is there any proper way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The Uri Class offers many properties https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.7.2

Try this

```
string val = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
```

or in your case if your request variable is an HttpRequest object, try:

```
string val = request.Url.AbsolutePath;
```

Comment: Pretty sure Request.Url.AbsolutePath includes the Ids though, like it would return "/app/company/employees/5" not "/app/company/employees"

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath

Comment: Pretty sure Request.Url.AbsolutePath includes the Ids though, like it would return "/app/company/employees/5" not "/app/company/employees"

Comment: Milan, you are able to test my hypothesis out yourself. I have already provided you with sufficient info to solve this. Don't worry, you are a new contributor, and maybe are not aware of these things. If you are using Visual Studio you can set a breakpoint or use the Locals or QuickWatch panes. Good luck